# Use "this.id" when addEventListener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, click

I want to get the id of an element create in javascript when we click on him.

For example:

```
    var input_check  = document.createElement("INPUT");
    input_check.id = 1;
    input_check.type = "checkbox";
    input_check.addEventListener("click", test);


    //Come here when s1 click on the checkbox
    function test(id){
        console.log(id);
    }
```

Obviously with this example I can't print "ID" cause I need to "generate" with javascript something like this :

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox" onClick="test(this.id)">
```

With the previous example I have something like this :

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox" onClick="test()">
```

Comment: Check the object that is passed to the event handler, and what `this` is: [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do exactly what you did when writing the onclick function as an attribute value.

```
input_check.addEventListener("click", function () {
    test(this.id);
});
```

Or just write `test` to expect to be called as an event listener in the first place:

```
input_check.addEventListener("click", test);
function test(event) {
    console.log(this.id);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To generate the input in HTML, you must add the input you created to the body, like this:

```
document.body.appendChild(input_check);
```